# How to pass very big variable with a redirect in the backend?

Tags: magento2, session, register, registry

I will create a redirect with a very big custom variable in the Magento 2 backend.

Now I use this method:

```
$resultRedirect->setPath('custom/url/index',array('_query'=>array('very_big_array'=>$arr);
```

When I try this, my server says: **This URL is too long**.

How can I pass a very big variable within my redirect?
Maybe the only way is: set a session? But if yes, how can I do this? Do I need this Session manager?

```
\Magento\Backend\Model\Session $backendSession
```

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: from where to where to you want to pass the varibale? Could you explain the use case? Maybe the session is indeed the right place for it

Comment: I have created a custom order Mass Action. When a user selects a few orders, this Mass Action function redirects the selected orders to my custom Magento 2 admin module. And when a user selects 200 orders, it's a very big array for a url...

Answer (score 1):

ok, since this query can get uncontrollably long, it definetly should not be a url param.

One way would be to store the data in the backend session (as you already described).

Another way would be to use the DataPersistor provided by the Magento2 Framework:

```
Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface
```

this seems to be a new method to store data between requests in magento2, like used here in the product/save action: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save.php#L153